# jquery - how to grow/shrink an image on mouseover

Tags: jquery, onmouseover

I have two circles on a page where if I hover over circle1 the second circle (circle2) to the right enlarges. I am trying to use jquery to have circle2 do the same thing, but instead both circles flash and circle2 gets misplaced.

Here is the html I have so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="practice.css">
<title>Practice</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="circle1" id="circle1"></div>
    <div class="circle2" onmouseover="growCircle()" onmouseout="shrinkCircle()"></div>
</div>

<script>
function growCircle() {
        document.getElementById("circle1").className = "circleBig";
}
function shrinkCircle() {
        document.getElementById("circle1").className = "circle1";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my css

```
.body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 500px;
    background:#CC0000;
    display:block;
}

.circle1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #dadada;
/*  position: absolute; */
/*  top: 50%; */
/*  left: 30%; */
/*      margin-right: -50%; */
/*      transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
    float:left;
}

.circle1:hover + .circle2 {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    }

/* .circle2 { 
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    float: right;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    } */

.circle2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #dadada;
/*  position: absolute; */
/*  top: 50%; */
/*  left: 30%; */
/*      margin-right: -50%; */
/*      transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
    float:right;
}   

.circleBig {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #dadada;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're only changing one circle, the event handlers are only affecting the other circle `<div class="circle1" id="circle1"></div>`. Also note that this is an element, not an image.  To use the element that the event handler is on you would want to pass the parameter `this`. And use that in the functions. Like so:

```
 <div id="circle1" class="circle1" onmouseover="growCircle(this)" onmouseout="shrinkCircle(this)"></div>
```

And the JavaScript functions are simpler:

```
function growCircle(ele) {
    ele.className = "circleBig";
}
function shrinkCircle(ele) {
    ele.className = "circle1";
}
```

Here is a preview of those changes: take a look at [**this fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/vnhwom00/)

Now the reason why it seems to move off to the right is because it's changing in respect to the top-left corner, not the center. You just need to move the element over a bit to make up for that (100 pixels to the right and 100 pixels down, or the other way depending on how you look at it.), so you need to add the following CSS to the `circleBig` class:

```
.circleBig {
    ....
    position:relative;
    right: 100px;
    bottom: 100px;
    ....
}
```

And we have what we want.

[**Here is the final result**](http://jsfiddle.net/vnhwom00/3/)

To have one element affect another element (and not just itself) we can modify the JavaScript to be like so:

```
function growCircle(ele) {
    document.getElementById(ele).className = "circleBig";
}
function shrinkCircle(ele) {
    document.getElementById(ele).className = "circle1";
}
```

Then you can pass the *id* of what you want to change, passing `"circle1"` changes the size of the element with the *id* `circle1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's really simple. Just add

```
.circleBig {
     width: 500px;
     height: 500px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     background: #dadada;
     float:left;
   }
```